# What do you call the maximum number of recent values used for calculating an average

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, technical, mathematics

A sensor measures some physical quantity (like temperature). The measured value is tapped every 100ms or so. An average is calculated over the `x` most recently measured values. I.e. with every new measurement the oldest value will be discarded, the new value will be included and the average will then be recalculated.

What is a common term for the size `x`?

EDIT:
After having found out, that the term for this specific kind of average is "moving average" and having read the corresponding wikipedia article, I believe "sample size" may be the right term. Would that be correct? Is there a better word?

Comment: If it's an automatic process, isn't the sample size always the same, e.g., 10 temperatures every 100 ms? So if you're saying this in a technical paper, wouldn't you want to be specific? OTOH, if you're discussing the process in a general way, wouldn't it be reasonable to use _X_ (or some other variable) and define it, e.g., "_where X is the number of measured values in the averaged sample_"? "An average is calculated over the **sample size** most recently measured values" doesn't sound grammatical or reasonable to me, but "An average is calculated over the most recently measured values" does.

Comment: Yes, the sample size would always be the same, but the sampled values change. Besides it's not for a technical paper - it's for a programming API and therefore I need a short, but concise word.

Comment: "Sample size", "subset size" or (if `x` remains constant, "fixed subset size") would all be correct.

Comment: Then you need a programmer to answer. I'm not a programmer.

Comment: This is the "window" or "window size"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *sample size* would refer to the number of measurements that you use in your *moving average*.  It theoretically could be confused with the number of averages you compute from the data, so you might use something like *sample window size* to be clearer.